# How to create temporary directory in ant?

Tags: ant

I'd like to create a temporary directory in ant (version 1.6.5) and assign it to a property.

- The command "mktemp -d" would be ideal for this, but I cannot find similar functionality from inside ant
- I can't find any official function in the docs apart from the [tempfile task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/tempfile.html) which apparently only creates files, not directories.
- I'm considering using exec to call tempfile and get the result, however this will make my  build.xml dependent on UNIX/linux, which I'd like to avoid.

Background: I'm trying to speed up an existing build process which builds inside networked filesystem. The build already copies all the source to a temporary directory, however this is on the same filesystem. I've tested changing this to /tmp/foo and it gives a worthwhile speed increase: 3mins vs 4mins.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could combine the [tempfile task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/tempfile.html) with the `java.io.tmpdir` [system property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29) to get a file path to use to create a temporary dir:

```
<project default="test">

    <target name="test">
        <echo>${java.io.tmpdir}</echo>
        <tempfile property="temp.file" destDir="${java.io.tmpdir}" prefix="build"/>
        <echo>${temp.file}</echo>
    </target>

</project>
```

Note that the `tempfile` task does not create the file (unless you ask it to). It just sets a property which you can use to create a file or dir.

> This task sets a property to the name of a temporary file. Unlike
>   java.io.File.createTempFile, this task does not actually create the
>   temporary file, but it does guarantee that the file did not exist when
>   the task was executed.

Output in my environment:

```
test:
     [echo] C:\Users\sudocode\AppData\Local\Temp\
     [echo] C:\Users\sudocode\AppData\Local\Temp\build1749402932
```

Answer (score -2):

The answer above only hints at how to create a temporary directory. The point is that  merely returns a string. A more complete answer is

```
<target name="temptest" description="test making tempdir">
    <tempfile property="mytempdir" destdir="${java.io.tmpdir}"/>
    <tempfile property="mytempfile" destdir="${mytempdir}"/>
    <tstamp>
        <format property="now" pattern="MMMM dd yyyy"/>
    </tstamp>
    <copy tofile="${mytempfile}">
        <string value="today=${now}"/>
    </copy>
    <property file="${mytempfile}"/> 
    <echo message="It it now ${today}"/>
</target>
```